# C++: recursively replace all instances of a letter in a string with another letter

Tags: c++, string, recursion, replace, function-definition

I'm just going through some textbook c++ questions and one of them is to write a function which *recursively* replaces all instances of a certain letter in a string with another letter. I know that there are pre-existing functions for this, but because this chapter focuses on recursion, this question insists that the solution must be recursive. So I wrote all this out in c++ and it was fine but then I read the footnote to the question and what it says is: "for the manipulation of string objects, only the methods *at* and *length* (i.e. *size*) are allowed as well as the operator *+*". whaaa? I just don't see how you could make this happen without *str.substr(pos,len)* but I would be thrilled if somebody could find a way. Thanks a bunch to that special someone yo.

Here's the best code my hamster brain could come up with (also a small iterative alternative commented out at the beginning).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// iterative solution
/* string replace (string in, char from, char to) {
  string res;
  for (int i{0}; i < in.length(); i++) {
    if (in.at(i) == from)
      res += to;
    else
      res += in.at(i);
    }
  return res;
} */

// recursive solution
string replace (string in, char from, char to) {
  if (in.empty())
    return "";
  char first{in.at(0)};
  if (first == from)
    return to + replace (in.substr(1), from, to);
  else
    return in.at(0) + replace (in.substr(1), from, to);
}

int main () {
  string in;
  char from, to;
  cout << "Word: ";
  cin >> in;
  cout << "from: ";
  cin >> from;
  cout << "to: ";
  cin >> to;
  cout << in << " --> " << replace (in, from, to) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide a default argument that keeps track of the index:

```
string replace(string in, char from, char to, int i = 0) 
{
  if (i == in.length()) 
    return in;
  if (in.at(i) == from) 
    in.at(i) = to;
  return replace(in, from, to, i + 1);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6sWTNF).

This only uses `at()`, and `length()`, and doesn't even use `+`.

Also, avoid `using namespace std;`, it's bad practice.

Comment: oh wooow that's it! thanks a bunch
and thanks for the tip, I'll omit the `using namespace std;` in the future

Comment: As an optimization you could do `return replace(std::move(in), from, to, i + 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the footnote

> I read the footnote to the question and what it says is: "for the
>   manipulation of string objects, only the methods at and length (i.e.
>   size) are allowed as well as the operator +".

it seems the function should look the following way

```
std::string & replace( std::string &in, char from, char to, std::string::size_type pos = 0 )
{
    if ( pos < in.size() )
    {
        if ( in.at( pos ) == from )
        {
            in.at( pos ) = to;
        }

        replace( in, from, to, pos + 1 );
    }

    return in;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string & replace( std::string &in, char from, char to, std::string::size_type pos = 0 )
{
    if ( pos != in.size() )
    {
        if ( in.at( pos ) == from )
        {
            in.at( pos ) = to;
        }

        replace( in, from, to, pos + 1 );
    }

    return in;
}   

int main() 
{
    std::string in( "Hell& W&rld!" );
    char from = '&';
    char to = 'o';

    std::cout << in << " --> "; 
    std::cout << replace( in, from, to ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hell& W&rld! --> Hello World!
```

Take into account that "to replace all instances of a letter in a string with another letter" means that the source string must be changed. This in turn means that the source string must be passed to the function by reference.

Comment: oh yeea, so gotta use some sort of index either way, thanks. oh yeah, if the changed string is to be used later in the programme, I should pass it by reference, good advice!